# How to overwrite HTML node before it loads original content?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a javascript file which find the tag on the page and overwrite what HTML has in e.g. when the page load the HTML is seen `<h1>This is innerHTML </h1>` and after the js file has loaded, it is `<h1>This para has been reloaded</h1>`.

If the net is fast it won't be visible but as I am creating it for end user/testing, I want to assume the internet is slow so only the JS code is loaded in the selector.

Is it possible?

```
    <div>
        <p id="one">This is the inner Text</p>
    </div>
```

```
let p = document.getElementById("one");
p.innerHTML = "This is now rewritten"
```

Comment: Usually you want the content to be the same after the page has been loaded for all clients. An overlay with a transparent background and an animated spinner is what is usually used for slow connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `div` visible after your desired event completion like this:

```js
let p = document.getElementById("one");
p.innerHTML = "This is now rewritten";
document.getElementById('myContent').style.display="block";
```

```css
#myContent{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myContent">
 <p id="one">This is the inner Text</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand how does it work? is it because inline CSS has more prcedence then a linked styled sheet? I tried it on my own, should myContent CSS be inlne or linked?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. But i suggest u to use stylesheet instead of inline css